# Duplicate of deleted question

Tags: discussion, duplicates, deleted-questions

I came across [a question](https://serverfault.com/q/852996/214507) which is marked as duplicate of a deleted question. Is it appropriate for a duplicate link to be pointing to a deleted question? If not, what would be the proper way to deal with such a situation?

Comment: The proper way would for OP to just undelete the target question and finally start to follow the advice both me and EEAA repeatedly gave him, so he might have a chance to actually get proper help with his original problem. For some reason or another, he doesn't seem to want to do this. I might end up reclosing this as "off-topic, not enough data" though, to remove the dead link.

Answer (score 8):

This is a consequence of the OP doing it wrong in asking a bad question, creating a new question instead of editing the port information into the original, then deleting the first instance after the second one was marked as a duplicate, and finally opening a third question to ask the same thing.

Probably the proper response is to close the second instance for a different reason (and there are a few of those), but since the questions are lousy, and it's a problem of the OP's own making, I'm not sure why the mods should have to go through the trouble of dealing with it.  At the end of the day, we've got three useless, close/delete-worthy questions, one of which is deleted, two of which are on hold.  Seems perfectly cromulent to me.